# Are ldc.i4.x and ldc.i4 x instructions interchangeable and semantically identical?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, il

There are some loading instructions in CIL such as `ldc.i4.0`, `ldc.i4.1`, `ldc.i4.2`, `ldc.i4.3` …

I wonder, is it possible to use `ldc.i4 1` instead of `ldc.i4.1` or `ldc.i4 5` instead of `ldc.i4.5`?

Comment: Sure.. but why? They take more space, and there seems to be no benefit.

Comment: Is this a question about code injection? In which case then presumably the answer is no, not easily, _because_ they take more space? May be worth clarifying the context here, and what is meant by 'replace'.

Comment: @James indeed, the question is unclear there; I chose to interpret it as "are these two things interchangeable and semantically identical?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely legal to use `ldc.i4 1` in place of `ldc.i4.1`. The single-byte op-codes are given *for efficiency and brevity* in the most common scenarios. In particular, all those `ldarg.0` (1 byte) would quickly add up to **significantly** increase the size of your assembly if they were `ldarg 0` (3 bytes), as would the `ldc.i4.1` in things like `i++`; `ldc.i4 1` is 5 bytes instead of 1.

You are not obliged to use them. I would actually *expect* (untested) the JIT to spot the more verbose usage and treat it the same anyway, although it would not be *required* to do so.

Personally, when I'm doing "emit" or similar, I just use a utility method that emits the *most appropriate* code(s) for any given value / local / argument / etc.

Answer (score -2):

here it's the good article about CLR code injection:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time

Comment: is it possible to use ldc.i4 1 instead of ldc.i4.1 or ldc.i4 5 instead of ldc.i4.5?

Comment: Right. Question was about the specific instructions. Not so much if it's possible or how to inject IL in general.